# Absolute maximum of Riemann Zeta Function

Tags: riemann-zeta

The question os fairly simple, though I couldn’t find its answer on the internet.

Is the norm of the complex output value of the Riemann Zeta Function limited? Or can I plug in input values to make it as large as I want?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What input values do you allow?  In the most general input it seems the [Maximum Modulus Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_modulus_principle) tells us it will be unbounded.

Comment: $\zeta$ has a simple pole at $1$, so it's unbounded.

Comment: @hardmath Any complex number different than 1. Is the Maximum Modulus Principle applicable since the function has a pole (as Daniel Fischer mentioned)? Or the principle does not relate to that?

Comment: @DanielFischer This means that the function applied to numbers very close to 1 (in all directions) outputs large normed numbers?

Comment: Yes, if $\lvert s-1\rvert$ is small, then $\lvert \zeta(s)\rvert$ will be large. We have (near $1$) $$\zeta(s) = \frac{1}{s-1} + \gamma + O(s-1)$$ where $\gamma$ is (as usual) the Euler-Mascheroni constant.

Comment: @DanielFischer thanks, that solves my question:)

Answer (score 2):

A somewhat interesting way to ask about (un)boundedness of the Riemann zeta function $\zeta(s)$ for any "complex number different than $1$" is to look at the entire function $\zeta(s) - \frac{1}{s-1}$.

As a now deleted Comment on the Question mentioned, [the power series expansion](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.tjm/1270133547) at $s=1$ of this function is given by [the Stieltjes constants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stieltjes_constants) $\gamma_n$:

$$ \zeta(s) - \frac{1}{s-1} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n!} \gamma_n (s-1)^n $$

Here $\gamma_0 = \gamma \approx 0.577\ldots$ is the [Euler-Mascheroni constant](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/123531/3111).  All of the other singularities of $\zeta(s)$ besides the simple pole at $s=1$ [are removable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1766038/analytic-continuation-of-riemann-zeta-function), so the power series above converges in the entire complex plane.

By applying the [Maximum Modulus Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_modulus_principle) to this entire function, we find that it is *unbounded* in the complex plane once we confirm that it is *not constant*.  It is enough to know that $\gamma_1 \approx −0.0728\ldots$ is nonzero.  More information is given at the Wikipedia "Stieltjes constants" article linked above.

Indeed the Riemann zeta function has a curious [universality property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function#Universality) in the critical strip, where for any holomorphic function we can find a location that approximates it arbitrarily well.  This is another way to see how the Riemann zeta function is unbounded away from its simple pole at $s=1$.